# Build a custom image in Azure using Packer and Managed Identity fails

Tags: azure, packer, azure-managed-identity

I'm trying to create a custom VM Image in Azure using Packer with Managed identity, I'm running the packer template from an Azure Ubuntu VM.

But I'm getting when runing this command `packer build CustomLinuxImage.json`:

> azure-arm: Microsoft Azure: To sign in, use a web browser to open the
> page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code ******* to
> authenticate.

When I go to login I got :

> Approval required This app requires your admin’s approval to:
>
> Have full access to the Azure Key Vault service
>
> Access Azure Service Management as organization users (preview)
>
> Sign in and read user profile

What I find so strange is to ask me all that access permission if I'm already logged in to the Managed identity using

```
az login --identity
```

I'm new on Azure, could you help please? Any comment will be apperciated!
[image]